# Unsupported operand types error when declaring default params as INF

Tags: php, parameters

Consider the following function:

```
checkBetween($value, $lowerBound = -INF, $upperBound = INF);
```

It is giving me an error `Unsupported operand types`. Why is it illegal to declare function params with default value of `INF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-INF` requires run-time evaluation, and that isn't permitted for default values in function definitions

Note that PHP >= 5.6 ***does*** support this type of run-time evaluation

[demo](http://3v4l.org/TYkCZ)